# How to solve corrupted file Error while reading excel files using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am facing **Unsupported file error** while reading using Pandas

```
FilePath = os.path.join(r"C:\", "Sourcefile.xlsx")
URL = 'https://www.ams.usda.gov/sites/default/files/media/GTRTable2.xlsx'
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

with open(FilePath, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.content)
    if len(response.content) == None:
        sys.exit(1)

Data = pd.read_excel(FilePath, header = None, dtype = object)

"xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'<HTML><H'"
" raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)"
```

Comment: I have no issues reading the file directly from the URL, `df = pd.read_excel('https://www.ams.usda.gov/sites/default/files/media/GTRTable2.xlsx')`

Comment: Hi @MrFuppes I agree with ur comment. but the issue here is the code i am running in seperate server there if i use you code it results in "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden" , So i used requests here with proxies to Avoid 403 error

Comment: well, the detour via downloading the xlsx works also fine for me, only the first line seems messed up, I changed it to `FilePath = os.path.join("C:/", "Sourcefile.xlsx")`